# Как сделать так, чтобы метки попадали в тестовые выборки?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, классификация, xgboost

```
xgboost.cv(params=params, dtrain=dtrain, num_boost_round=1000, nfold=8)
```

При большом количестве разбиений, например 8, метки перестают попадать в тестовые выборки, насколько я поняла из ошибки:

> Check failed: !auc_error AUC: the dataset only contains pos or neg
>   samples

При `nfold=4` всё работает без ошибок.

Какое  более правильное и универсальное решение с кроссвалидацией для будущих данных, т.к. `nfold=4` для неизвестных данных может не подойти?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте воспользоваться параметром `stratified=True`.

```
import xgboost as xgb

xgb.cv(params=params, dtrain=dtrain, num_boost_round=1000, nfold=8, stratified=True)
```

При использовании данного параметра, при создании тестовой подвыборки (`fold`) алгоритм будет пытаться сохранить такое же процентное соотношение классов как и во всем датасете.

---

Если ваш датасет сильно разбалансирован (например число меток позитивного класса - 1%, а число меток негативного класса - 99%), то стоит подумать о предварительной балансировке датасета. Для работы с разбалансированными данными существует удобный модуль [imbalanced-learn](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html), позволяющий сбалансировать данные практически всеми известными и популярными методами: `RUS`, `ROS`, `SMOTE`, `SMOTEENC` м многими другими.

Comment: Благодарю. Работает. За модуль отдельное спасибо! Осваиваю